# Script to rename '../foo' to asset_path('foo')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, macros, textmate, replace

This is not limited to Rails developers, but I would assume it's pretty common to have to do this since Rails 3.1.

I'm looking for a script/some method of replacing everything of the form

`'../foo/BLAHBLAH'`

to `<%= asset_path 'BLAHBLAH' %>`

where `foo` is the name of the asset type, so it can be either `images` or `fonts`.

Anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Can either be done with a combination of `find` and `sed` or a global replace with your favorite editor e.g. `vim`, `textmate`,...

Comment: @topek Ok. I use textmate. Can you help me out a bit? I know how to write a regex to find `../foo/DASFSAFAS` but I don't know how to capture that DASFSAFAS string

Comment: In Textmate there is find in project (Command-Shift-F) that should perform a project wide search. I don't have Textmate installed, maybe some one else can help on the details.

Comment: You could try searching for "\.\./images/(.*)" and replacing with "<%= asset_path($1) %>". I think that should do the trick.

Comment: @topek This works pretty well... The problem I'm having is that the regex matches stuff that's all included in one line. For example `url('../images/fdassdfa') blah blah '` will assign $1 to `../images/fdassdfa') blah blah `

Comment: Sure, the regex needs to have a right delimiter. `\.\./images/(.*?)[\)'"]` uses non greedy search and delimites on the right with either ), ' or "

Comment: @topek awesome. Format your comments as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Instead of matching "\.\./images/(.*)" use "'\.\./images/([^']*)'" so it has to be inside single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a global search and replace.

In *Textmate* you can hit `Command-Shift-F` to enter a project wide search. Then search for `\.\.\/images\/(.*?)[\)'"]`and replace it with `<%= asset_path('$1') %>`

With *`find` and `sed`* it's a simple one liner:

`find PROJECT_DIR -type f -name "*.html" -exec sed -i -e 's/\.\.\/images\/\([^)'\''"]*\)/<%= asset_path("\1")/g' {} \;`

And in *Vim* you can do:

```
:args ./**
:argdo %s/\.\.\/images\/(.*?)[\)'"]/<%= asset_path('\1')/g
```

Comment: Note for the first regex: forward slashes must be escaped. (S/O won't let me edit it because it's under a 6 character edit)